# SSRS - Can I hardcode Select ALL for multivalue parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I'm facing a known problem with [default values for a cascading parameters](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/268032/default-does-not-get-refreshed-for-cascading-parameters). Since my parameters are coded in MDX I cannot find any specifc idea for a workaround.

Rather than trying to change a parameter query, I thought to check if there is a possibility of hard coding SELECT ALL for a cascading, or any parameter for that matter.

This is my Parameter dataset:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Organisation].[Cost Centre Code and Description].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
SELECT  
    [Measures].[ParameterValue]
ON COLUMNS , 
[Organisation].[Cost Centre Code and Description].[Cost Centre Code and Description].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 
FROM 
(SELECT STRTOSET(@CC_Caption, CONSTRAINED) ON COLUMNS FROM 
[CUBE] )
```

Would anyone have an idea how to hardcode `SELECT ALL` for an SSRS parameter?

Thanks for any points :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in Custom Code. Not straightforward though. I have used in when using SharePoint list as a source. Should be applicable here. I will use a sample "Client" parameter.

1. Create a parameter @ClientHelper. Set it to hidden, multi-value, available values come from your dataset query and default values from your dataset query as well.
2. Create a parameter @Client. Set it to visible, not multi value, and available values of "specify values". Leave the label column blank and put in "=Split(Code.RemoveDups(JOIN(Parameters!ClientHelper.Value, “|”)), “|”)" as the values expression. You can set the default value to whatever you want.
3. Note that @ClientHelper has to come before @Client in the list of parameters.

The custom cod you need is below. You can perhaps change it to meet your need if you don't need to remove dups.

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDups(ByVal items As String) As String
Dim noDups As New System.Collections.ArrayList()

Dim SpStr as String()
SpStr = Split(items ,"|")

For i As Integer=0 To Ubound(Spstr)
If Not noDups.Contains(SpStr(i).Replace("&","&").Trim()) Then
noDups.Add(SpStr(i).Replace("&","&").Trim())
End If
Next

Dim uniqueItems As String() = New String(noDups.Count-1){}
noDups.CopyTo(uniqueItems)
uniqueItems.Sort(uniqueItems)

Dim strRetValue AS String = String.Join("|", uniqueItems)
strRetValue = "All|" + strRetValue
Return strRetValue
End Function
```

Now you will still need to have the filters and logic in place in your dataset queries that do the cascading...but this gives you the "ALL" option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not go to default values for the parameter and use "Get values from a query" and then supply a query that has all of the values?